# Learning how to use SQLXML data types

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlxml

I've been given the challenging task to become familiar with using SQLXML data types in C# using Microsoft SQLServer. None, of my C# or database books cover this and there are no tutorials I can find on the web. All I've managed to find is an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.aspx). I've been using C# for a long while mainly in WinForms for desktop applications. However, I've only recently gotten into using C# for database stuff.

Can someone point me to a webpage that will give me a quick crash course on how to use this class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MSDN article *might* be relevant

[Using SQLXML Bulk Load in the .NET Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171878.aspx)

I have ZERO experience with SqlXml. And you're right... it took a bit of digging to find this. The SINGLE relevant google hit was to the API doco in MSDN.

Sux to be you ;-)

Cheers. Keith.

**EDIT:** I should have said: The above artice is linked from this old (2005) forum post: [C# sqlxml example](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/172164-sql-xml-c-example), so I'm presuming that the article itself might be getting a bot long in the tooth, so check which versions of stuff they're talking about, K?